# Draw JPanel picture - Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have a problem to draw a point on `JPanel`. I want to put point with her position.
Because on the panel I load a picture. For each click on button I would to add point on panel.

But i don't appear on the panel.

File simpleIHM :

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class simpleIHM extends JFrame{


  JPanel JpLeft = new JPanel();
  JPanel JpRight = new JPanel();
  JButton btn1 = new JButton("Show");
  JLabel msgX = new JLabel("X :");
  JLabel msgY = new JLabel("Y :");
  JTextField textX = new JTextField(5);
  JTextField textY = new JTextField(5);

  public static int x,y = 0;

  JLabel img = null;
  BufferedImage image;

  public simpleIHM(){
        img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Centre.png"));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JpLeft.add(img);
        PanelIMG imgPanel = new PanelIMG();
        JpLeft.add(imgPanel);
        getContentPane().add(JpLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JpRight.add(msgX);
        JpRight.add(textX);
        JpRight.add(msgY);
        JpRight.add(textY);
        JpRight.add(btn1);
        JpRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        getContentPane().add(JpRight, BorderLayout.EAST);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        showIMG("./Centre.png");
        //!!
        btn1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
                                {
                                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("CLICK!");
                                        x = Integer.parseInt(textX.getText());
                                        y = Integer.parseInt(textY.getText());
                                        System.out.println("X "+x+ "| Y "+y); img.repaint();
                                    }

                                });
  }

    public void showIMG(String test){
        try
        {
            File input = new File("Centre.png");
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
        }
        catch (IOException ie)
        {
        System.out.println("Error:" + ie.getMessage());
        }
    }

  public static void main(String [ ] arg) {
        simpleIHM IHM = new simpleIHM();
       } 
}
```

File PanelIMG

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class PanelIMG extends JPanel{

public PanelIMG()
{

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawOval(simpleIHM.x, simpleIHM.y, 5, 5);
    System.out.println("Paint Component");
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if I didn't misunderstood, you're trying to repaint a JLabel with new X and Y coords, which are taken when you click on a JButton, and new coords will be the position where the mouse clics inside that button, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it is correct. But the point with the new coords appear on the picture. Each clic ont the button there is a new point with the new coords on the picture.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have misinterpreted the question, but it seems that you want to paint a point over an image. But in the posted code, you actually painting an image in one panel and the point in another.

You can create a panel with a background image and paint a point in that panel. Below is the example that demonstrates.

Also please note some minor comments:

- There is no need to extend top level container `JFrame` unless you add new functionality;
- Use  `DocumentFilter`, `JFormattedTextField` or handle exception in case of invalid
  input from user (ie NumberFormatException thrown from
  `Integer.parseInt()`);
- The trick with public static x,y members that are used by other classes is a dirty hack, avoid it.
- Get familiar with Java [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) section in particular.

Here is a demo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

class ImagePanelDemo {
    static class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        private Image image;
        private Point point;

        ImagePanel(Image image, Point point) {
            this.image = image;
            this.point = point;
        }

        public void setPoint(Point point) {
            this.point = point;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (image != null)
                return new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), 
                        image.getHeight(this));
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            if (image != null)
                g.drawImage(image,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
            if (point != null)
                g.fillOval(point.x, point.y, 5, 5);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        try {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
                "https://duke.kenai.com/comfyChair/ComfyChairRadSmall.jpg"));           

            final ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel(image, 
                    new Point(10, 10));

            frame.add(imagePanel);

            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

            final JFormattedTextField xField = new JFormattedTextField(
                    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
            xField.setColumns(5);
            final JFormattedTextField yField = new JFormattedTextField(
                    NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
            yField.setColumns(5);

            JButton updateButton = new JButton("Update");

            buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("x:"));
            buttonPanel.add(xField);
            buttonPanel.add(new JLabel("y:"));
            buttonPanel.add(yField);
            buttonPanel.add(updateButton);

            updateButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
            {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    try {
                    imagePanel.setPoint(new Point(
                            Integer.parseInt(xField.getText()), 
                            Integer.parseInt(yField.getText())));
                    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```